# Play framework action response delayed when creating multiple futures

Tags: scala, playframework

In the following action it should return response immediately after hitting URL but instead it waits till all the Future blocks are started and then only sends response. It waits till "Starting for group 10" is logged in console even though "Returning from action" is logged immediately after hitting URL.

```
def test = Action { implicit request =>
    Future.successful(0 to 150).foreach { items =>
      items.grouped(15).zipWithIndex.foreach{ itemGroupWithIndex =>
        val (itemGroup, index) = itemGroupWithIndex
        Future {
          logger.info("************** Starting for group " + index)
          itemGroup.foreach { item =>
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            logger.info("Completed for item " + item)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    logger.info("************** Returning from action **************")
    Ok(views.html.test("test page"))
}
```

I am not able to understand reason behind this delay and how can i make this action send response immediately.

Play framework version 2.5.9

Comment: Use Action.async() and return the response from the future itself instead of outside of future block.

Comment: I don't want to wait till future completes and i don't need result of future in response. I tried .async but it does not help.

Comment: Future in Future in Future - it's too complicated to debug it. Can you simplicate the example of the problem? Any way, I am pretty sure that this is about the thread pool, you just use all the threads available in the default pool or so. Here is a good answer, I hope it will helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579030/play-framework-what-happens-when-requests-exceeds-the-available-threads

Comment: @AndriyKuba you are right, i tried using a different thread pool and worked as expected. Thank you for, I now understand reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Action is not Async. You have a synchronous endpoint which is why you see the Returning from action printed immediately on the console. You should probably use the Action.async as your processing type. Using async Actions will drastically improve the overall performance of your application and is highly recommended when building high throughput and responsive web applications.

Comment: I tried async method as well but did not help. As you can see that i don't need computation of futures to be available in response so i just need to run that future code in background.

Comment: Can you try removing the Thread.sleep and see if your method returns immediately as you hit the URL?

Comment: It does return immediately but Thread.sleep is used here to simulate a blocking task. Actual code is call to a slow network API

Comment: You cannot guarantee how Play will handle your Future's. Can you perhaps try using a different thread pool other than the default one for the Futures? This might probably help!

Comment: i tried using a different thread pool and worked as expected. Thank you, I now understand reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Two points in your code needs to change

1. **Asynchronous Action**: Because you are using Future, the action should be asynchronous: `Action.async{...}`.
2. **No Blocking Code**: The whole point of using Future and asynchronous programming is not to have a code that "blocks" the execution. So I suggest to remove the `Thread.sleep(1000)` part of the code.

Note that if you write your code non-blocking way; whenever the action method get the result; it will perform the required action(s), such as logging or providing the view.

Answer (score -1):

This is because there are race conditions in your Futures.

You need to ensure that you are returning a single `Future[T]` and not a `Future[Future[T]]` (or any layered variances).

If the Futures are independent of each other, use `Future.sequence`

example:

```
 def future: Future[String] = Future.successful("hi")


 def action = Action.async { _ =>
   val futures: Seq[Future[String]] = (1 to 50).map(_ => future()).toSeq
   val oneFuture = Future.sequence(futures)
   oneFuture
 }
```

This will avoid race conditions

FYI, this has nothing to do with the Play framework. This is concurrent programming in scala.